# JavaScript variable Import yields "assignment to undeclared variable" error

Tags: javascript, import

I'm trying to import variables from one .js file to another but it won't work. I even uploaded my files to an external server so that I don't get the "blocked by CORS policy" error.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="script2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my script.js:

```
import { my_str } from './script2.js';

console.log(my_str);
```

And here is my script2.js:

```
const my_str = 'Hello world';

export default my_str;
```

The error I get is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable my_str
```

Does anyone know how I make this work? Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, I had to put curly braces around the "export" function and skip the default in script2.js:

```
const my_str = 'Hello world';

export { my_str };
```